# Shell Script Copy All Files and Subdirectories - Folder Names With Spaces

Tags: shell, copy

I am trying to copy all files and subdirectories using shell script. The problem is some of the folders names have spaces.

```
cp -r "//shrdata/Legal/test location/test folder/*" "//shrdata/Legal/open access/"
```

The error I get is "The System Cannot Find the File Specified"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
cp -r "/shrdata/Legal/test location/test folder"/* "/shrdata/Legal/open access/"
```

For the `*` to work properly, it must be outside of quotes.

#### Example

Suppose that we have a `test folder` with two files:

```
$ ls -1 test\ folder/
file1
file2
```

Now, let's try putting the `*` in quotes:

```
$ echo "test folder/*"
test folder/*
```

Because the `*` is in quotes, it is not expanded into a list of filenames.  Instead, it is merely treated as a literal character.  Consequently, if we try to copy files this way, we will get a file-not-found error because no file is named `*`:

```
$ cp "test folder/*" target
cp: cannot stat ‘test folder/*’: No such file or directory
```

If we place the `*` outside of quotes, then *pathname expansion* will be performed:

```
$ echo "test folder"/*
test folder/file1 test folder/file2
```

This means that this form will work properly when used with `cp`.